# Iptables limit user access time and mac

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, opensuse

I am trying to create an iptable chain to kick my daughter off her ipad during the night. With the mac only filter I can block access but when I add time it no longer works. Does anyone see an issue with this chain?

```
##Parental Controls
#iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -m mac --mac-source 60:21:c0:41:1b:a1 -j DROP
iptables -N blocked_access
iptables -A blocked_access -j LOG --log-prefix 'BLOCK TEST'
iptables -A blocked_access -p ALL
iptables -A blocked_access -m mac --mac-source 60:21:c0:41:1b:a1
iptables -A blocked_access -m time --timestart 16:00:00 --timestop 17:55:00 --weekdays Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu
iptables -A blocked_access -j DROP
```

It is also worth noting, that in OpenSuse, regardless of the timezone set, the time specified is GMT

Comment: Try --days instead of --weekdays

Comment: Opensuse 11 uses weekdays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the entirety of your iptables rules, the custom chain "blocked_access" will never be read.

Rather, have a rule to 'shunt' processing to the custom rule first, e.g.:

```
-A INPUT -p ALL -m mac --mac-source 60:21:c0:41:1b:a1 -j blocked_access
```

*then* you define the rules for your kid inside the "blocked_access" chain.

Comment: It is not the entirety of the iptables, but it is what the problem is! Thank you!